# java: Trying to add to an object list and getting nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I'm really sorry if this seems like a trivial question, but I'm not having any luck.

I've created a custom object similar to

```
    public class Foo {
        long id = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        String label = null;

        public void setId(long in){
        this.id = in;
        }

        public void setCounter(int in){
        this.counter = in;
        }

        public void setLabel(String in){
        this.label = in;
        }
}
```

I then create a list in another class

```
    public class ActivityThingy extends MainActivity {
        List<Foo> bar = new ArrayList<Foo>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                function();
        }

        private void function(){
            Foo kit = new Foo();
            kit.setId(1);
            kit.setCounter(1);
            kit.setLabel("");
            bar.add(kit);
        }

    }
```

Then I try to add an object to it in another method of the same class the list is created in.

The object list item is being added in a method within the class that the list is initialized in. The list is intended to be global to the class so that the method can be called repeatedly to add multiple items to the list based on user input.

Every time though, I get a null pointer exception. Obviously, I want it to add the item to the list instead of throwing that exception.

What else could I be overlooking?

I'm using Android Studio BTW.

Comment: You probabley have a wrong order of the creation i.e. you are trying to add the "Foo" to "bar" before "bar" is created.

and just a tip..if you want to get help on SO better post more code (preferably the whole class) since posting it like you did is vague and does not supply enough information of where your problem may happen.

Comment: So I am actually initializing the list in the class constructor and then invoking bar.add(kit) in a method within that class.
Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Have to implemented describeContents and writeToParcel, these to methods of Parcelable. Because I run same code and not getting error.

Comment: @Chitrang, I actually am in the full class. I had just grabbed the beginning of the class and renamed some stuff for simplicity. It wouldn't run at all if I hadn't implemented describeContents and writeToParcel. It runs right up until I add that item to a list.

Thanks though!

Comment: @Velogiraptor Judging by fact that you don't have editor badge in your profile I assume that you may not know how to edit your question to provide more content. If that is the case then simply use [[edit]] button under it.

Comment: @Pshemo I didn't know there was a badge for going back and editing your posts and comments. Strange. I actually edited it several times. Just posted another edit though. I hope that helps clarify. The class is too large to post here, even if I cut it down to just the involved methods. It just comes down to everything working fine right up until I add an item to the list. Then NPE. I thought declaring a global list would solve the order of initialization while being global. Is it possible it didn't?

Comment: Not sure, why this question was put on hold as "off topic". That doesn't make sense. Unclear, maybe. Off topic? No. I'll make a deal with the mods. If I have to be clear in my question, you have to be clear in your reasons.

Comment: @Benjamin Hi. I saw something about this question being closed and it says you edited it last. May I ask why? You can imagine how frustrating it might be for a newly learning person to have their question taken down without a clear explanation.

Comment: @Velogiraptor I actually voted to reopen it, and it seems that I'm not the only one (4/5 reopen votes so far). I personally don't see anything wrong with your question, sometimes people react a bit too fast to "vote to close" reviews! Hopefully it'll be reopened soon.

Comment: @Benjamin Oh! I still don't know how it all works here. :) I didn't  see where the vote was, although I'm sure it's somewhere. I'll look for it. I've since found the answer to my question, and it turned out to be more complicated that what I placed in the question. I will update the question later with exactly what I did wrong and a reply as to how I fixed it. Thanks so much! This community has been invaluable to me for learning what my noob mistakes are. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happened for posterity.

I had the object as described above and set the object values as described as well. The problem is, I was also passing in a value for that object through intent extras.

Here's where the code above blew up on me.

When I passed that object from another activity; it reset the value of "label" to null as declared in the new object. The string in the object with a default value of null was my issue.

My solution was to change

```
String label = null;
```

To

```
String label = new String();
```

And I no longer got the null pointer exception.

I will edit this answer with more detail if anyone has any more questions. Please comment if more detail is required.

Answer (score 0):

According to code provided by you in the question, you are setting `id, counter and label in id` see your code when you are calling `setCounter(int in)` you store it like `this.id = in;` it should be `this.counter = in;`

Replace your `Foo` class with the below one:

```
public class Foo {
        long id = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        String label = null;

        public void setId(long in){
        this.id = in;
        }

        public void setCounter(int in){
        this.counter = in;
        }

        public void setLabel(String in){
        this.label = in;
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a copy paste error in the example code. In the real class, it was correct. I have edited the example, and thanks for the catch!